# Camera is being used by another application -- which one?

Tags: ipad, camera, facetime

I was using FaceTime this morning, and during the call, the "Camera is being used by another application" screen appeared.

I've searched and I found https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250893855, which says "Quit all applications that are using the FaceTime camera".

But I *don't have* another application using the camera -- FaceTime *was* using it, so how did some other application steal the camera from it? If it can be stolen, how do I find out which application that was? If it can't be stolen, why did FaceTime suddenly decide, mid-call, to do this?

Note that I've also looked under Privacy / Camera; there are *no* applications listed as having  permission to use the camera (not even FaceTime).

(iPad mini, 5th gen, iOS 13.5.1)

Comment: It may have been a software crash where the device wasn’t cleanly released.  Try restarting the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

MicroSnitch or OverSight might help. See https://tidbits.com/2020/07/22/feeling-paranoid-micro-snitch-tells-you-if-your-mac-is-spying-on-you/

EDIT: these are for macOS, not iPadOS.  My apologies.  I'm leaving it here in case these references are useful to others though.

Comment: That software is for macOS, but the OP is using an iPad. Do they make software for iOS?

Comment: @Allan Very good point. I wasn't reading properly - apologies. I'm no expert, but sadly I doubt it is possible to write a 3rd party app on iOS that would do the same job.